# .NET Interop: Using an assembly in the current directory

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, interop, com-interop

I'm trying to use a .NET assembly from VB6 via interop without placing it in the GAC and without using the /codebase argument for regasm.exe.

From what I understand, when I run regasm.exe on a .NET class library, it creates a registry entry for each class in the class library telling the COM clients they should load mscoree.dll that serves as a proxy wrapping .NET objects for COM use. Mscoree.dll uses the InprocServer32/Assembly key in the registry for the class to determine which class library contains the implementation of the class.

If I use /codebase with regasm.exe or put my class library in the GAC, everything works OK; but as far as I can figure out from the scattered documentation, mscoree.dll should look for the assembly in the current directory and in the path if /codebase hasn't been used (and therefore there is no CodeBase entry in the registry for the class) and it can't find it in the GAC.

The C# code is as simple as can be:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace myinterop
{
    [Guid("B1D6B9FE-A4C7-11DD-B06B-E93056D89593")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class MyServer
    {
        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

And the problem reproduces with a VBScript one liner that I put in the same directory as the compiled DLL:

```
object = CreateObject("myinterop.MyServer")
```

What am I missing here? Is there a definitive description of the way mscoree.dll looks up the assemblies somewhere?

BTW, I'm using .NET 2.0 and yes, I know I should put my assemblies in the GAC, I'm just wondering why this doesn't work as advertised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(VS.80).aspx):

> **/Codebase** : Creates a Codebase entry in the
>   registry. The Codebase entry specifies
>   the file path for an assembly that is
>   not installed in the global assembly
>   cache. You should not specify this
>   option if you will subsequently
>   install the assembly that you are
>   registering into the global assembly
>   cache. The assemblyFile argument that
>   you specify with the /codebase option
>   must be a strong-named assembly.

It appears that it does work as advertised. If you don't put your assembly in the GAC, then you need to use /codebase so that the filepath is accessible.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want, I think you need to create .manifest files for both your .NET assembly and your VB6_App.EXE (referencing the .NET assembly). Check Google for registration-free COM.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that. Cool!